# How to remove spaces, and show only the first character from a second field with cut and unix tools?

Tags: linux, unix, text

I have a text file with names per each line, like:

```
john doe
roger smith
john kennedy
```

I would like to translate it to be:

```
johnd
rogers
johnk
```

I know how to remove spaces using `tr`, I can display use space as a delimiter and display the second field with `cut`, and then pass that output to cut and only display the first character, but I am unsure how to combine these steps to get the output I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s\n", $1, substr($2, 1, 1) }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` is probably best as mentioned above, but an alternative is to loop through the file and use `printf`:

```
while read firstname surname; do
   printf "%s%s\n" ${firstname} ${surname:0:1}
done < file.txt
```